# How do I link two fields to the same table in ServiceNow?

Tags: servicenow

Forgive my ignorance for the proper terminology, but let me try to explain what I want to happen.

I have two custom fields on the incident table/form. I have created a custom table with 2 columns. I have figured out how to reference the table in one of the fields, allowing me to search the entries. Now I want to link the field selection to the other field via the custom table I made. When I make a selection in field A, I want field B to populate with the other column on the same row Field A pulled from in the first place. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want what's commonly referred to as a "derived field" or a dot-walked field.

You have a reference field which stores the reference to the other table, and want a second field on the form that shows another field on that referenced table. You don't actually need to create a new element, you just need to add a dot-walked form element.

Once you have the reference field added, go to Personalize/Configure the form layout.

- In the slushbucket of available fields, you'll notice that reference
  fields show up in green text with a little [+] next to them.
- Select your reference field and a little button will show up between the two
  lists, just above the "Add" button
- Click that button and the left-side available fields will show the fields available on that reference field's table.
- From here, select that second field that you want to display on your form, and bring it over to the right side where you want it.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, thank you! Another question... Is it possible to have bi-directional dot-walked fields? One field auto-populates the other and vice versa?

Comment: You can only walk down into a reference field's fields.  Walking up is a one-to-many relationship that's visualized by a Related List.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your help. I'm used to manipulating table output with SQL statements, ServiceNow is confusing by comparison. I guess it's just a matter of learning all these little gui tricks.